# retrieving variable columns from Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-4

My DB has a generic structure which was created to support alot of different type of things.
Therefore there is a Product table with 5 columns but then there is a AttributeGroup and Attribute table.

The AttributeGroup specifies extra types of properties of the Product, So there are say 30 rows in AttributeGroup all with an ProductID relating back to the Product Table.  Then for every instance of the Product there is an entry in the Attribute Table which holds the value for that instance of the Product.  Thus Attribute table has a AttributeGroupID and a ProductID.

There is a stored procedure which returns the most usual properties of the the AttributeGroup Table plus the initial 5 columns of the Product table.  The sproc takes ProductID and an extra string input which we put a comma-deliminated string of the names of the extra fields in AttributeGroup Table.  It then returns a set of all instances of the Product and joins AttributeGroup and Attributes, uses the SQL Pivot command and returns all the data in columns.

However sometimes the data has 8 columns sometimes 15.  The EntityFramework calls the sproc but only returns 8 primary fields.  It uses a complex type.  Is there anyway to use a List or Dictionary object to load any extra column over the initial 8 so this can be binded to some view.